# Encode URL with PHP, show + instead of %20

Tags: url, encoding

I want to encode the post's title so I can add it to my URLs. The problem is that urlencode() gives me an URL such as:

Title:

```
Samsung Nexus S + Hard Case
```

URL:

```
Samsung%20Nexus%20S%20+%20Hard%20Case
```

And I want one more friendly like:

```
Samsung+Nexus+S+Hard+Case
```

I don't know what should happen to the '+' symbol. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the spaces with `+` since `%20` is the url encoding of a space. Here's an example of space replacement in PHP:

```
str_replace(' ', '+', $url_encoded_string);
```